# Dot product for similarity in word to vector computation in NLP

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec, similarity, softmax

In NLP while computing word to vector we try to maximize log(P(o|c)). Where P(o|c) is probability that o is outside word, given that c is center word. 
[image]

U<sub>o</sub> is word vector for outside word
V<sub>c</sub> is word vector for center word
T is number of words in vocabulary
Above equation is softmax. And dot product of U<sub>o</sub> and V<sub>c</sub> acts as score, which should be higher the better. If words o and c are closer then their dot product should be high, but that is not the case with dot product. Because of following:
Consider vectors 
A=[1, 1, 1], B=[2, 2, 2], C=[100, 100, 100]
A.B = 1 * 2 + 1 * 2 + 1 * 2 = 6
A.C = 1 * 100 + 1 * 100 + 1 * 100 = 300
Vectors A and B are closer compared to A and C, however dot product A.C >A.B 
So Dot product is acting as distance and not as similarity measure. Then why is it used in softmax. 
Please help me make my understanding better

Comment: it is possible the metric is a variation of cosine similarity (which is a normalised dot product, very common in NLP), you should provide the source of the reference you mention

Comment: Reference: Stanford's course on NLP  (Time = 12:22)  https://youtu.be/kEMJRjEdNzM?list=PLoROMvodv4rOhcuXMZkNm7j3fVwBBY42z&t=742

Answer (score 1):

The reference points to the [word2vec library](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3781) ([source code](https://github.com/tmikolov/word2vec)).

It does not use normalised vectors during training (although it indeed uses the [cosine similarity metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) for semantic comparisons on already trained vectors).

The reasons for using only dot product instead of cosine similarity during training can be due to:

1. **Dot product is a variation of cosine similarity**.
2. **Length captures some semantic information** in the sense that length can correlate to frequency of occurance in a given context, so using dot product only captures this information as well (although for strict similarity testing cosine metric is still used)
3. When vectors are normalised the **two metrics coincide**.
4. Efficiency (doing less computations)

References:

1. [Why does the word2vec objective use the inner product (inside the softmax), but the nearest neighbors phase of it uses cosine? It seems like a mismatch.](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-the-word2vec-objective-use-the-inner-product-inside-the-softmax-but-the-nearest-neighbors-phase-of-it-uses-cosine-It-seems-like-a-mismatch)
2. [Should I normalize word2vec's word vectors before using them?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177905/should-i-normalize-word2vecs-word-vectors-before-using-them)
3. [Measuring Word Significance using Distributed Representations of Words](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02297)
4. [word2vec Parameter Learning Explained](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.2738)

Comment: Reference: Stanford's course on NLP  CS224N Lecture-2 on youtube (Time = 12:22)  https://youtu.be/kEMJRjEdNzM?list=PLoROMvodv4rOhcuXMZkNm7j3fVwBBY42z&t=742

Comment: see my updated answer and references therein

Comment: Point (3) above is relatively more convincing, but i guess they are not normalizing to unit vector length.

Answer (score 0):

The dot product is the magnitude of the projection of one vector $v$ to $w$, which is not a very good similarity measure, however:

$$
v \cdot w = \lVert v\rVert\lVert w\rVert Cos(\theta)
$$

Being $\theta$ the angle between the 2 vectors.
And:

$$
v \cdot w = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \cdot w_i
$$

Being: $\lVert v\rVert = \sqrt{v \cdot v} $
With very simple math we can obtain:

$$
\frac{v}{\lVert v\rVert} \cdot \frac{w}{\lVert w\rVert} = Cos(\theta)
$$
As

$$
-1 \le Cos(\theta) \le 1
$$

In case the vectors are divided by their norm (normalization) we can say " the higher the dot prod the more similar"

Comment: if magnitude of vectors is 1, i.e. if vectors are normalized, then it makes sense as it'll become cosine similarity. However I doubt if vectors are normalized for magnitude to be 1 i.e. |v|=1

Comment: Small correction  |v|^2 = v.v  :)

Answer (score 0):

Vectors Uo and Vc are more or less similar in magnitude. And magnitude is very small. Dot product normalized by length of vectors is cosine similarity.